# Error: throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not decompiled

Tags: java, apk, reverse-engineering, decompiling, decompiler

I am trying to reverse engineer an apk file. For this I'm using [jadx v 0.9.0](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) decompiler.

The problem is that jadx doesn't decompile all the functions, this is what I get instead:

```
private defpackage.dmw a(defpackage.dzy r3, defpackage.efb r4, defpackage.dve r5, java.lang.String r6, defpackage.dmx r7, android.content.Context r8) {
        /*
        r2 = this;
        if (r7 == 0) goto L_0x00cf;
        r0 = r7.a();
        if (r0 == 0) goto L_0x0017;
        r0 = r7.b();
        if (r0 == 0) goto L_0x000f;
        goto L_0x0017;
        r3 = new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
        r4 = "Synchronous ResponseHandler used in AsyncHttpClient. You should create your response handler in a looper thread or use SyncHttpClient instead.";
        r3.<init>(r4);
        throw r3;
        if (r6 == 0) goto L_0x0037;
        r0 = r5;
        r0 = (defpackage.duz) r0;
        r0 = r0.a;
        if (r0 == 0) goto L_0x0032;
        r0 = "Content-Type";
        r0 = r5.a(r0);
        if (r0 == 0) goto L_0x0032;
        r6 = a;
        r0 = "AsyncHttpClient";
        r1 = "Passed contentType will be ignored because HttpEntity sets content type";
        r6.c(r0, r1);
        goto L_0x0037;
        r0 = "Content-Type";
        r5.b(r0, r6);
        r6 = r5.e();
        r7.a(r6);
        r6 = r5.k();
        r7.a(r6);
        r6 = new dmp;
        r6.<init>(r3, r4, r5, r7);
        r3 = r2.i;
        r3.submit(r6);
        r3 = new dmw;
        r3.<init>(r6);
        if (r8 == 0) goto L_0x00ce;
        r4 = r2.d;
        monitor-enter(r4);
        r5 = r2.d;   Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        r5 = r5.get(r8);     Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        r5 = (java.util.List) r5;    Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        if (r5 != 0) goto L_0x0071;  Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        r5 = new java.util.LinkedList;   Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        r5.<init>();     Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        r5 = java.util.Collections.synchronizedList(r5);     Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        r6 = r2.d;   Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        r6.put(r8, r5);  Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        monitor-exit(r4);    Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        r5.add(r3);
        r4 = r5.iterator();
        r5 = r4.hasNext();
        if (r5 == 0) goto L_0x00ce;
        r5 = r4.next();
        r5 = (defpackage.dmw) r5;
        r6 = r5.a;
        r6 = r6.get();
        r6 = (defpackage.dmp) r6;
        r7 = 0;
        r8 = 1;
        if (r6 == 0) goto L_0x009a;
        r6 = r6.a();
        if (r6 == 0) goto L_0x0098;
        goto L_0x009a;
        r6 = 0;
        goto L_0x009b;
        r6 = 1;
        if (r6 != 0) goto L_0x00bd;
        r6 = r5.a;
        r6 = r6.get();
        r6 = (defpackage.dmp) r6;
        if (r6 == 0) goto L_0x00ba;
        r0 = r6.a();
        if (r0 != 0) goto L_0x00b4;
        r6 = r6.a;
        if (r6 == 0) goto L_0x00b2;
        goto L_0x00b4;
        r6 = 0;
        goto L_0x00b5;
        r6 = 1;
        if (r6 == 0) goto L_0x00b8;
        goto L_0x00ba;
        r6 = 0;
        goto L_0x00bb;
        r6 = 1;
        if (r6 == 0) goto L_0x00be;
        r7 = 1;
        if (r7 == 0) goto L_0x00c5;
        r5 = r5.a;
        r5.clear();
        if (r7 == 0) goto L_0x0079;
        r4.remove();
        goto L_0x0079;
        r3 = move-exception;
        monitor-exit(r4);    Catch:{ all -> 0x00cb }
        throw r3;
        return r3;
        r3 = new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
        r4 = "ResponseHandler must not be null";
        r3.<init>(r4);
        throw r3;
        return;
        */
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not decompiled: defpackage.dmo.a(dzy, efb, dve, java.lang.String, dmx, android.content.Context):dmw");
}
```

According to the solution suggested on this [issue](https://github.com/skylot/jadx/issues/218) I must get everything decompiled with --show-bad-code, however this didn't work for me!

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: I'd recommend trying a different decompiler.

Comment: @Antimony this is the 3rd compiler I've tried and I always get the same thrown exception. Hopefully,  [this](https://github.com/skylot/jadx/issues/682#issuecomment-499425481) will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this tool [Jar Explorer](http://dst.in.ua/jarexp/index.html?l=en).
There are tree different decompilers. Should help.

Comment: @yosra hey can you tell me how to solve this problem? Thank you so much

Comment: Just download the application and open the class you needed to decompile there. I case any error try to another decompiler in Menu->Decompilers

Comment: @TrungBui sorry for the delay, what I did here is I decompiled the project into Java, thus many functions were not decompiled which is normal in this case, developpers do this to protect their projects. the only work around I'd found was to decompile the project into smali language, and then you can convert the smali into java, hope it helps, good luck :)

Comment: @yosra How did you convert smali to java?

Comment: @A.J. It's been more than year now, but I remember that I haven't found a direct way to decompile a smali into java. so what I did was: convert smali --> dex --> java. Here is a link that might help you: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2430413